# Use html node from Javascript variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use the attr() method on a html node, which I have a reference to in a normal variable in Javascript.

Now, the problem is that this node is not returned by a jQuery selector, but with normal Javascript: `var myNode = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;`

Now, I would like to do something like:

```
jQuery.attr(myNode, "style");
```

Obviousely, this does not work. Is there any way to use such jQuery method on a non-jQuery variable (a normal node)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`range.commonAncestorContainer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer) returns a DOM element just wrap it as a jQuery object, like this:

```
$(myNode)
```

For example:

```
var style = $(myNode).attr('style');
//or set it:
$(myNode).css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Thanks. By the way, would something like $(myNode).(":parent") be possible?

Comment: @Tom - Yeah of course, `$(myNode).parent()` :) See the other tree traversal (moving around) functions available here: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/